# Ignore prerequisite building output only from GNU make

Tags: makefile, build, gnu, io-redirection

What is a simple way to ignore all output from GNU make's building prereqs, but keep all the rest (both stdout and stderr).  I'm working with a script that randomly uses either stream.  So, for example, if I have

```
t: main.native ${STUFF}
        ./${SCRIPTS}/run-tests
```

How can I just do `make t &> output` and get the output without all the rebuild info from the prerequisites prepended (eg. only outputs from `run-tests` in the above example)?

Comment: Do you want Make to do this for `t`, or for the primary target whatever it is?

Comment: I'm interested in an easy general solution -- currently I;m post-processing , , eg. with sed or such

Comment: There is no way to get make to "separate" output from different recipes... how should it do that?  Where would it put the different "batches" of output?  Make has only two output options: stdout and stderr, and really there's only one: stdout (because stderr is for errors).  Also, make doesn't even capture the output of recipes (unless output sync is enabled): when make invokes a command that commands writes directly to whatever stdout it was given, which is the terminal (or a file or pipe if redirected).

Comment: thanks, when you put it like that it sounds fairly simple -- but, I see enough arcane hacks with make that it feels like it should be able to do just about anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not quite sure what you're looking for, but you can do this:

```
t: main.native ${STUFF}
    @echo PREREQS_DONE
    ./${SCRIPTS}/run-tests

>make t | sed '1,/PREREQS_DONE/d'
```

Or this:

```
t:
    @$(MAKE) real_t  | sed '1,/PREREQS_DONE/d'

real_t: main.native ${STUFF}
    @echo PREREQS_DONE
    ./${SCRIPTS}/run-tests
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I'm doing -- I just figured there is probably a way to separate the output for the stages as well

Comment: @picklerick: There is, but you have to ask your real question.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize it was vague, which part is unclear?  I just want to separate all the normal compilation output for prereqs, eg. compiling, llinking, etc, from the output of the script in the example rule (which is annoyingly not easily separable by output streams)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I just do `make t &>` output and get the output without all the rebuild info from the prerequisites prepended (eg. only outputs from run-tests in the above example)?

Build targets `main.native ${STUFF}` first and then run tests only. E.g.

```
tests : main.native ${STUFF}

run_tests : tests
    ./${SCRIPTS}/run-tests

.PHONY : tests run_tests
```

And then:

```
make tests && make run_test &> output
```